# Firebase Notifications Compose Message: "The version you have selected to target will also target unintended versions"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a Notification only to users of "x.x" version but when I select "Version matches exactly x.x" the mentioned message appears. Why is this? How do I target only the version I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, you give an app both a version number and a version string. Firebase Notifications uses them both in combination and this warning appears when your selected version string "x.x" matches version numbers that also match other version strings (such as "x.y").

By choosing version string "x.x" Firebase Notifications will target all app installs that have a version number that matches "x.x". If you have built some app version that has version string "x.y" but that shares the same version number then instances of that app version will also be targeted.

You cannot really get around this warning in the console, you have to make a point of only changing version name and version number at the same time when building your app.

Comment: I see, I may have left the same version number while changing the version name during development. Now that I uploaded a newer version changing both values at the same time, the error went away. Thanks!